# Cannot assign "'value'": "model.attr" must be a "model" instance

Tags: python, django

I am new en django, I have the next models in models.py

```
class Persona(models.Model): 
    cedula_p= models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    Nombre_p= models.CharField(User, max_length=100)
    fecha_nacimiento_p= models.DateField()
#11111, User1, 01/01/1991
#22222, User2, 02/02/1992
#Others 13998 items

    def __str__(self):
       return "{0},{1}".format(self.cedula_p, self.Nombre_p)

class Producto(models.Model):
    Nombre_prod = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    precio = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.Nombre_prod)
        
class compra(models.Model):
    cedula_prod= models.ForeignKey(Persona, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The forms.py is:

```
class formulario_compra(forms.ModelForm):
    cedula_prod = forms.CharField() 
#I have 14.000 elements, for that reason i don't use select o choicefield

    class Meta:        
        model = compra
        fields = '__all__'

#input test cedula_prod: 11111 or 22222
```

and the views.py

```
class crear_persona(CreateView):
    model = Persona
    form_class = formulario_persona
    template_name = 'web1.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('EjemploVista1')

class crear_compra(CreateView):
    model = compra
    form_class = formulario_compra
    template_name = 'Web2.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('EjemploVista2')
```

in the forms, in formulario_compra i don't use the default form for cedula_prod because would be a list with some values (14000), so, I use a charField. I need to verify that the input exists in the model Persona.cedula_p. At the moment to try to save appear:

Cannot assign "11111": "compra.cedula_prod" must be a "Persona" instance.

I try different things, but I can't solve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Because your model take `ForeignKey` you cannot assign `character` type. So, you have to use sthg like [*ModelChoiceField*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

```
class formulario_compra(forms.ModelForm):
    cedula_prod = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Persona.objects.all())
```

You can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) to check the corresponding form and model fields.